# Django : NoReverseMatch for HttpResponseRedirect with kwargs

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the following error:

> NoReverseMatch at /updatebooking/
>
> Reverse for 'common.views.myview'
> with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'msg': "hello", 'case':
> 'success'}' not found.

common/views.py

```
def view1(request):
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('common.views.view2', kwargs= {"msg":"hello","case":"success"}))

def view2(request,msg=None,case=None):
    ...
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^test1/$','common.views.view1',name='my_view1'), 
url(r'^test2/$','common.views.view2',name='my_view2'),
```

This line `reverse('common.views.view2', kwargs= {"msg":"hello","case":"success"})` is throwing the error.

The error comes only when I use `kwargs`. Following codes work:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my_view2'))
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('common.views.view2'))
```

Kindly help me resolve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using `reverse` with `kwargs` parameters django tries to find a parameterized url route. In your example, matching route would be similar to

```
url(r'^test2/(?P<msg>\w+)/(?P<case>\w+)$','common.views.view2',name='my_view2')
```

Refer to [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) and [`URLDispatcher`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) documentation for more details. Unfortunately, both URLDispatcher and reverse manuals are a little bit cryptic about this particuar feature.

Answer (score 1):

Your url doesn't have `msg` or `case` parameter, that's why Django can't find it. See the paramenter `slug`in this example:

`url(r'^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', 'test.views.detail', name="test-detail")`

I believe that you're trying to pass a message/notification to another view. If that's the case, you should check [the messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/).